# TypeError: string.trim is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying a basic code to trim a function. But it displays error TypeError: string.trim is not a function. Please help why is this so.

```
const isEmpty = (string) =>
{
  if (string.trim() === '') return true;
  else return false;
};
```

This is to check the whether a string is empty or not. I'm making a react project with firebase.

Comment: Are you sure `string` *is* a string? Also why not just `string => string.trim() === ''`?

Comment: Yes.. String is a string. I don't know what causing up the problem.

Comment: Well e.g. `"".trim` will tell you it is a function, so either string isn't a string or you're on some pre-ES5 runtime that doesn't have the method.

Comment: So how do I correct it? How do I make sure it is a string?

Comment: If you check out my answer below, the conditional: `if(typeof string !== "string")` returns `true` if the `string` variable is not a string.

Comment: The answers below already tell you that. Or you could do it in more of a duck-typed style, `string.trim && string.trim() === ''`, but it's not clear what result you'd expect for a non-string - is it empty or not?

Comment: A one liner for your function would be `const isEmpty = (string = '') => String(string).trim() === ''; `

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though the `string` variable is sometimes not a string. You could amend the function to account for this like:

```js
const isEmpty = (string) =>
{
  if(typeof string !== "string"){  // check if the string variable is some type other than string
    // do something here
  }
  else {
    return string.trim() === '';
  }
};
```

Comment: I've tried this but according to my code it show the email is empty that's why I am using trim function.

Comment: Right, in that case you would want to return `true` inside of: `if(typeof string !== "string")` because the type of the `string` variable is likely something like `null` or `undefined` in which case you'd want to return `true` as it represents an empty `string` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Just make sure the 'string' parameter is actually a string

Use the builtin function typeof to confirm that

```
console.log(typeof(string)) // should be string
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not get it.

Answer (score 0):

The "trim is not a function" error occurs when we call the trim() method on a value that is not a string. To solve the error, convert the value to a string using the toString() method or make sure to only call the trim method on strings.